# How do I remove icon overlays from unversioned folders in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

How do I remove icon overlays from unversioned folders in Tortoise SVN? I am using latest Tortoise and Windows 7. A question mark appers on the unversioned folder, and this was not the case in older versinos.

Answer (score 1):

Check under Settings / Icon Overlays / Overlay Handlers:

[image: TortoiseSVN overlay handlers]